# pyoidc as RP crashing at sha_compress

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am using pyoidc as RP (relying party) to google OP. I have obtained client-id and client-secret out of band. Also the authorization request happens out of pyoidc and obtained the "QUERY_STRING" which contains authorization code grant along with few parameters.

Then i have instantiated "pyoidc client" object and filled with the above information. Now when i am invoking "client.do_access_token_request" to obtain ID Token and access token, i see from debugs, I have got the ID Token and AccessTokenResponse.

While validating the ID Token, my python client application is crashing with segmentation fault.

```
DEBUGS:
 from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
DEBUG:oic.oauth2.message:Found signing key.
DEBUG:jwkest.jws:Picking key by key type=RSA
DEBUG:jwkest.jws:Picking key based on alg=RS256, kid=b6f8d55da534ea91cb2cb00e1af4e8e0cdeca93d and use=
DEBUG:jwkest.jws:Picked: kid:b6f8d55da534ea91cb2cb00e1af4e8e0cdeca93d, use:sig, kty:RSA
Segmentation fault
```

stacktrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
sha_compress (hs=0x81cd698) at src/hash_SHA2_template.c:183
183     src/hash_SHA2_template.c: No such file or directory.
        in src/hash_SHA2_template.c
(gdb) bt
    #0  sha_compress (hs=0x81cd698) at src/hash_SHA2_template.c:183
    #1  0x00a1e77a in SHA256_update (hs=0x81cd698, buf=<value optimized out>, len=574) at 
        src/hash_SHA2_template.c:366
    #2  SHA256_update (hs=0x81cd698, buf=<value optimized out>, len=574) at 
    src/hash_SHA2_template.c:347
    #3  0x009d744f in ffi_call_SYSV () at src/x86/sysv.S:61
    #4  0x009d7280 in ffi_call (cif=0xf7b4df38, fn=0xa1e6f0 <SHA256_update>, rvalue=0xf76b4cf0, 
    avalue=0xf76b4ce0) at src/x86/ffi.c:213
    #5  0x009c3dca in cdata_call (cd=0xf76400b0, args=0xf76427fc, kwds=0x0) at 
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3025
    #6  0x0019fa34 in _PyObject_FastCallDict () from /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
```